# Refresh fragment setText attribute

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm try to using the class Fragment all working well, but when try to use variable get from te server, the fragment dont update the values.

This is my code:

```
public class report_fragment extends Fragment {

    private BarChart barChart;
    private ListView list;
    public RequestQueue queue;
    private Float ris;
    String cu;
    Button bSave;

    private String userID,email,name,surname,age,privilegi;
    TextView tExer, tRis;
    String risultato, disciplina;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report_fragment, container, false);

        barChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.bargraph);
        tExer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tExerc);
        tRis = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tRis);

        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        if (b != null) {

            name = b.getString("name");
            surname = b.getString("surname");
            age = b.getString("age");
            privilegi = b.getString("privilegi");
            userID = b.getString("user");
        }

        Log.d("iduser2", "" + userID);

        graficaDati(userID);

        Last(userID);

        tExer.setText(disciplina);
        tRis.setText(risultato);

        return view;
    }

    private void graficaDati(final String ID) {
        //final TextView gTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        // gTextView.append("  entrato in Data");

        String url = "https://anto-mc.000webhostapp.com/atleti_statistiche2.php";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            final ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

                            ArrayList<String> theDates = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject out = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                String meteo = out.getString("meteo");
                                String dataa = out.getString("data");
                                String risultato = out.getString("risultato");
                                String score = out.getString("punteggio");
                                String tot= out.getString("tot");


                                Log.d("quiqui", ""+tot);

                                barEntries.add(new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(tot)));
                                theDates.add(dataa+"-"+meteo);
                            }

                            BarDataSet set1;
                            set1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Your score");
                            set1.setColors(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#ffffff")});

                            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
                            dataSets.add(set1);

                            BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

                            XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
                            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyCustomXAxisValueFormatter(theDates));

                            xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
                            data.setValueTextSize(10f);
                            data.setBarWidth(0.9f);

                            barChart.setData(data);
                            barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
                            barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                            barChart.invalidate();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("userID", ID);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }

    private void Last(final String ID) {
        //final TextView gTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        // gTextView.append("  entrato in Data");

Log.d("ciaoo","sei qui");

        String url = "https://anto-mc.000webhostapp.com/last.php";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            final ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

                            ArrayList<String> theDates = new ArrayList<>();
                            Log.d("ciaoo","sei qui2");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject out = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("ciaoo","sei qui2" +""+out);

                                String meteo = out.getString("meteo");
                                disciplina = out.getString("disciplina");
                                risultato = out.getString("risultato");
                                String score = out.getString("punteggio");
                                String tot= out.getString("tot");



                                Log.d("queryris",""+disciplina + "  "+ risultato);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("userID", ID);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }
}
```

I received the variables "risultato and disciplina" and I see the correct value just after navigating in this fragment at the second time.

Frist time I see the null variable.

I tried to use a refresh of the fragment but it doesn't work.

The bargraph working correctly, but the `setText` doesn't work. I tried to do the same like a bargraph I have a failure.

Does someone have a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the text inside your `onResponse` function. The values are not available until the network call is finished. So the `onResponse` function inside your `Last` function should look like this.

```
private void Last(final String ID) {
    //final TextView gTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    // gTextView.append("  entrato in Data");

    Log.d("ciaoo","sei qui");

    String url = "https://anto-mc.000webhostapp.com/last.php";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        final ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

                        ArrayList<String> theDates = new ArrayList<>();
                        Log.d("ciaoo","sei qui2");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject out = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.d("ciaoo","sei qui2" +""+out);

                            String meteo = out.getString("meteo");
                            disciplina = out.getString("disciplina");
                            risultato = out.getString("risultato");
                            String score = out.getString("punteggio");
                            String tot= out.getString("tot");

                            Log.d("queryris",""+disciplina + "  "+ risultato);
                        }

                        // Set the text here when it is available
                        tExer.setText(disciplina);
                        tRis.setText(risultato);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("userID", ID);

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

The key idea is to set the text after the values are available after your API call is returning with some values in it. When you are calling a server API, it is being executed in another thread other than the UI thread. It does not halt its execution inside the `onCreateView` function as you are expecting I think.

Hope that helps.